# Confused on Patching in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've read through the docs but am still pretty confused on patching in Python.  I have a `Contact` class and I've written the following functions:

```
def update_contact(name, phone, address, company, title, contact_id):
    contact = Contact(contact_id)
    set_contact_fields(contact, name, phone, address, company, title)
    return contact.update()

def set_contact_fields(contact, name, phone, address, company, title):
    contact.name(name)
    contact.phone(phone)
    contact.address(address)
    contact.company(company)
    contact.title(title)
```

So `Contact(contact_id)` grabs the `Contact` object with `contact_id`.  Then `set_contact_fields` sets the appropriate fields.  Finally, `contact.update` saves these changes (it's an API call).

I now want to unit-test update_contact to ensure that it's changing the old field values to the new ones, but I'm a bit unsure how to go about this.

From the `patch` docs, it looks like I might do something like:

```
@patch.object(Contact, 'update')
@patch.object(Contact, 'name')
@patch.object(Contact, 'phone')
@patch.object(Contact, 'address')
@patch.object(Contact, 'company')
@patch.object(Contact, 'title')

def test_update_contact(self, update, name, phone, address, company, title):
    contact = Contact()
    update_contact('name', 'phone', 'address', 'company', 'title', contact)
    # check that update was called with...
    name.assert_called_once_with('name')
    phone.assert_called_once_with('phone')
    address.assert_called_once_with('address')
    company.assert_called_once_with('company')
    title.assert_called_once_with('title')
    update.assert_called_once_with()
```

Unfortunately, this test fails.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong; help?

Thanks!

Comment: could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code.  My stack trace is: Testing started at 3:49 PM ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 153, in <module>
    testLoader.makeTest(getattr(testCaseClass, a[2]), testCaseClass))
AttributeError: 'TestLoader' object has no attribute 'makeTest'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: try to execute empty test first

Comment: @Jimilian Looks it can't find the path.object reference...hmm